# How to create an editable apk

Tags: android

Is it possible to make an android app for which the apk file is editable?
So that people can modify my apps

Comment: Ever heard of AIDE? 

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

Comment: What do you mean simple apps using app. Question is Not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Building an apk needs compile environment, and a running app in android can't offer these envs, so there is no way.

Comment: there is a way, since there are complete IDEs running on Android, and creating APKs on Android.

Comment: Thank you for your response